# Cross Origin Resource Sharing with Greasemonkey & Child Window

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, xss, greasemonkey, tampermonkey

I have a 100% client-side solution. I make a request for a web page. A Greasemonkey (GM) script is inserted into the page & reorganizes the page (which contains a table). The table now has buttons with javascript to launch a window that relates to each row as follows:

// In parent page:

```
var companyTable = data; // a table acquired with XMLHTTPRequest
var chartCode = chartGenFunct.toString(); // funct to gen a chart inserted by GM
var win = window.open('data:text/html;base64,'+ window.btoa(childWindow), '_blank');
```

where the childWindow string contains:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>GM Script Info</title>
        <style type="text/css"></style>
</head>
<body bgcolor="#FFFFFF">


<div id="companyTableDiv"></div>
<div id="companyChartDiv"></div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>

<script id="XXswScriptInitXX" type="application/javascript">
document.getElementById("companyTableDiv").innerHTML = window.opener.companyTable;
eval(window.opener.chartCode +"showTimeLine()"); // fills CompanyChartDiv

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

From the above parent & child code, you can see the idea is to pass window.opener.chartCode and window.opener.companyTable to the opened child window. The omnibox of the child window looks like:

```
data:text/html;base64,PCFET0NUWVBFIGh0bWwgU...
```

where the parent window's omnibox holds:

```
http://somewebsite.com/table
```

Here is the point where I say 'everything works in Firefox'. This does not work on Chrome with Tampermonkey (TM). The reason it does not work is that Chrome blocks it per as what seems to be a Cross Origin Resource Sharing issue per the error console logging:

> Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "null" from
>   accessing a frame with origin "http://somewebsite.com".  The frame
>   requesting access has a protocol of "data", the frame being accessed
>   has a protocol of "http". Protocols must match.

at line:

```
document.getElementById("companyTableDiv").innerHTML = window.opener.companyTable;
```

Bear in mind that this is a 100% client-side solution. How can I trick Chrome into allowing the child to see the opener's (parent's) data? (I already tried inserting document.domain = http://somewebsite.com and this does not work.)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue today, and the working solution for me was to use GM values.

Open the new window in a way that would trigger the same userscript to be run on it. Then you can create two 'streams' of data: in the direction of the parent and of the child.

For example, this how listening could look in parent script part:

```
var messageFromChild, childStreamControl;
childStreamControl = setInterval(function(){
    messageFromChild = GM_getValue('childStream', 0);
    if(messageFromChild != 0){
        GM_deleteValue('childStream');
        eval(messageFromChild);
    }
}, 50);
```

Broadcasting:

```
// stream = [preparedMessage1, preparedMessage2...]
var ownStreamControl;
ownStreamControl = setInterval(function(){
    if(GM_getValue('parentStream', 0) != 0 && stream.length > 0){
        GM_setValue('parentStream', stream.unshift());
    }
}, 50);
```

Answer (score 0):

I've run into the same problem, but I think I know a work-around, at least for up-to-5MB of static data in the parent window that you might want the child window to access.  Take advantage of the "[local storage](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html)" mechanism.  When you open the child window, do a data-dump at the same time to local storage. Then the child window can access the data there, instead of trying to get it directly from the parent.

Beware that local storage can be pretty ephemeral, if more than one web page wants to save something there after first doing a "clear" of all of it!  Your child window should probably grab the entire data block as fast as it can --and then deliberately delete it.  If the parent window is running JavaScript in the background, even while the child window is doing stuff, it might be able to notice the deletion, and put new stuff in local storage for the child window to find....

Comment: Thx -- It's funny -- about the same time I realized and just tested this out. I can put the same page's link info in:window.open('http://same_as_parent), '_blank') -- then in the child window, since I'm using Greasemonkey, I can overwrite the entire page and use variable passed into the child via window.opener.some_variable. This technique seems to work well. I'm still fine tuning and I think it should now work in Chrome too. Still -- my original question remains open for others to glean info.

Comment: Unfortunately for me, I want my child page to do more than just access parent-page data; I also want to access functions and objects on the parent page.  Those things can't be passed through Local Storage.  However, I've thought of an experiment to try, and if it works I'll be posting it as another Answer.

Comment: If I inspect the DOM, I can see my global variables AND code from the opener window. For example, the function main is window.opener.maincode. If only select functions are used, you can set global variables like "var funkshun = mainPageFunction.toString()" and this main page code will be accessible to your child page as window.opener.funkshun.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm not following your original explanation.  How does "the same page's link info" relate to the original parent and child?  That is, it seems to me you are talking about opening a third window, so which of the first two is opening it, and which of the first two is being re-opened?  In my case the initial page needs to do some secure stuff, but after it is done, it doesn't need to be secure any more (I wish there was a way to turn it off!).  None of the child-pages spawned by that initial page need security, but they do need to access stuff on the initial/parent page.

Comment: Ah - My situation ... the page somesite.com/example.pl presents page that gets posted back to itself and draws a different page w/ the same URL. In discussing with you, I used 'same page'. Instead, consider 'same page' to mean any page on the same site/domain (somesite.com). To avoid the the CORS restriction, when any page is returned from that site, you simply hijack that page with Greasemonkey by looking for the window.opener parent global vars like chldWin

if(window.opener) {  
  if(window.opener.chldWin) { // my global parent  
       document.body.innerHTML = window.opener.chldWin;